# multiple values for keyword argument in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am running into what appears to be a Python error on Google App Engine (localhost)
I am trying to use the Model.get_by_id() function but I run into a multiple keyword arguments error as I've pointed out in the comment in the code below. 3rd line from the bottom

I'm sure this is simple error, I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance!

```
'''
Created on 09/01/2013

@author: jonathan
'''
import webapp2_extras.security as security
from google.appengine.ext import db
import hashlib
import datetime

class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    passhash = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    authtoken = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    def __init__(self, username, password, email=None):
        authtoken = security.generate_random_string(entropy=256)
        passhash = security.generate_password_hash(password)
        super(User, self).__init__(username=username,
                                   passhash=passhash,
                                   email=email,
                                   authtoken=authtoken)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def check_password(self, password):
        return security.check_password_hash(password, self.passhash)

    @classmethod
    def check_unique_user(cls, username):
        return not bool(cls.all().filter('username =', username).count())

    def get_session_token(self, dt=None):
        ID = self.key().id()
        if not dt:
            dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%y%H%M%S")
        hashstring = "{0}${1}${2}".format(ID, dt, self.authtoken)
        return '{0}${1}${2}'.format(ID, dt, hashlib.sha256(hashstring).hexdigest())

    @classmethod
    def check_session_token(cls, session_token):
        if session_token:
            ID, dt = session_token.split("$")[:2]
            if ID.isdigit():
                user = cls.get_by_id(ids=int(ID))  # Raises TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'username'
                if user and user.check_session_token(session_token, dt):
                    return user
```

The rest of my code:

common.py #This one is still a work in progress...

```
'''
Created on 06/01/2013

@author: jonathan
'''
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response.out.write(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        templated_html = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return templated_html.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kwargs):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kwargs))

if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
    app_scheme = 'http'
else:
    app_scheme = 'https'
```

registration.py

```
'''
Created on 07/01/2013

@author: jonathan
'''
import common
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute
import re
from models.user import User

def getroutes():
    return [RedirectRoute(r'/signup', handler=SignupPage, name='signup', schemes=common.app_scheme, strict_slash=True),
            (RedirectRoute(r'/welcome', handler=WelcomePage, name='welcome', strict_slash=True)),
            (RedirectRoute(r"/login", handler=LoginPage, name="login", schemes=common.app_scheme, strict_slash=True)),
            (RedirectRoute(r'/logout', handler=LogoutPage, name="logout", strict_slash=True))]

username_pattern = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
password_pattern = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
email_pattern = re.compile("^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
def valid_username(username):
    return username_pattern.match(username)

def valid_password(password):
    return password_pattern.match(password)

def verify_password(password, verify):
    return password == verify

def valid_email(email):
    return email_pattern.match(email)


class SignupPage(common.Handler):
    def render(self, **kwargs):
        super(SignupPage, self).render("signup.html", **kwargs)

    def get(self):
        session_token = self.request.cookies.get("session")
        if User.check_session_token(session_token):
            self.redirect_to("welcome")
        self.render()

    def post(self):
        v_username = v_password = v_email = False
        username = self.request.get("username")
        password = self.request.get("password")
        verify = self.request.get("verify")
        email = self.request.get("email")
        params = {'username_error':'',
                  'password_error':'',
                  'verify_error':'',
                  'email_error':'',
                  'username':username,
                  'email':email}

        if valid_username(username):
            if User.check_unique_user(username):
                v_username = True
            else:
                params['username_error'] = "Username taken"
        else:
            params['username_error'] = "Invalid username"


        if valid_password(password):
            if verify_password(password, verify):
                v_password = True
            else:
                params['verify_error'] = "Passwords do not match"
        else:
            params['password_error'] = "Invalid password"

        if valid_email(email):
            v_email = True
        else:
            params['email_error'] = "Invalid email"

        if v_username and v_password:
            if v_email:
                user = User(username=username,
                            password=password,
                            email=email)
            else:
                user = User(username=username,
                            password=password)
            user.put()
            session_token = user.get_session_token()
            self.response.set_cookie("session", session_token)
            self.redirect(r'/welcome')
        else:
            self.render(**params)


class WelcomePage(common.Handler):
    def get(self):
        session_token = self.request.cookies.get("session")
        user = User.check_session_token(session_token)
        if not user:
            self.response.delete_cookie('session')
            self.redirect_to("signup")
        else:
            self.render("welcome.html", {'user':user})



class LoginPage(common.Handler):
    def get(self):
        session_token = self.request.cookies.get("session")
        user = User.check_session_token(session_token)
        if not user:
            self.response.delete_cookie('session')
            self.redirect_to("signup")
        else:
            self.render("login.html")

    def post(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')
        remember = self.request.get('remember')
        params = {}
        user = None

        if valid_username(username):
            user = User.all().filter('username =', username).get()
            if not user:
                params['username_error'] = "Can't find username"
        else:
            params['username_error'] = "Invalid username"

        if user and user.check_password(password):
            self.redirect_to('welcome')
        else:
            params['password_error'] = "Mismatched password"
            self.render('login.html', params)


class LogoutPage(common.Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.delete_cookie("session")
        self.redirect(r'/signup')
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an instance of User in your datastore where "username" is not a `StringProperty`, but a list.  When the db library fetches the entity and parses it, it's unable to convert the list into a `StringProperty`.

I'd suggest using the datastore viewer and checking that your entities actually have valid Strings for the username.

Edit: Just looked through the code again.  It's a very bad idea to override **init**.  The User class is not a typical class, but rather it's a metaclass for generate User instances.  ie, your User instances are not actually instances of your user class.  I suspect you're running into an issue there.

Comment: I've just tried clearing the data store but the problem occurs after a successful creation and storing of the first instance.